# How to know if the player that is sending data to server is the real player and not a fake one? (for facebook games)

Tags: facebook

I have a facebook game that is hosted in a html file and works with javascript. When user A arrives to the facebook game will send it's own uid to the server and make some stuff (doesn't matter what for this question).

Now my question is: how can I trust that user?

- I would like to not have another login/register step

Why I'm afraid?
Imagine that you open up the console and send a request with the user B id, I will blindly accept as true, even if you are user A!

*Maybe using OAuth2 and npm passport?*

Thanks,

Comment: Just send their access token to the server (or grab it from the cookie), and make an API request to `/me` with that token to see if the user id is genuine.

Comment: can you explain more, I'm a newbe in this, thanks

Comment: If you are not familar with how the login flow and the API works _in general_, then please start with the official docs. Ask more specific questions when you have a basic idea of how stuff works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your client, when you make the login with facebook api, grab it like this:

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response){
    this.__authToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
    this.__signedRequest = response.authResponse.signedRequest;
    this.__status = response.status;
    this.__userId = response.authResponse.userID;
    initFuture.done();
}.bind(this));
```

Then send it to the server. Here you will use the fbgraph node_module

```
var graph = require('fbgraph');
graph.setAccessToken(data.authToken);
graph.get('/me', {}, function(err, data){
    debugger;
});
```

The API for the graph

```
graph(url, arguments, callback)
url: String
arguments: Object
callback: function
```

Check the Graph API here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/